# Attaching an object to another context in EF 4

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4

I have a baseclass in my website with a property: CurrentUser.
The get method of this property will create a new context and get a User object from the database based on auth cookie information. So far so good.

But since the context is closed, all I can do outside this, is to call properties directly under User, for example FirstName.

But as soon as I try to get a relation for example, like CurrentUser.UserOffices this won't work since I didn't include UserOffices in the query.

Is there a way to create a new context outside the baseclass which I can attach the CurrentUser object to? I have tried ctx.Attach(CurrentUser) with no luck.

You may wonder why I don't include UserOffices. This is simply because there are very many relations to different tables and I don't want to include them all since it differs between my web pages what relations are needed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to Attach your entity and then explicitly load property:

```
ctx.Attach(CurrentUser);
ctx.LoadProperty(CurrentUser, u => u.UserOffices);
```

I'm not sure if this works with POCOs.

You can also query for object again with Includes specifing navigation properties you need.

The other choice is simply load UserOffices with Linq-to-entities query restricting where condition to current user.

Comment: Thanks. It worked perfectly. And after doing this I could also dig in deeper in the structure of UserOffice, just what I needed. Before you answerered I temporarily did like your other choice there which also works of course. The problem is that it feels unnecessary to get the object in the base controller first, and then again shortly after.